# mandrill merge tags not working for my template

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I have now spent quite a lot of time on this and still can not figure this out.

Here is my template that i have saved in mandrill->outbound->templates

```
Hello *|USERNAME|*

this is a *|TEMPNAME|* template
```

And here is the post request that i make from command line

```
curl -A 'Mandrill-Curl/1.0' -d 
'{"key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","template_name":"testTemp","template_content" : [],
 "message": {"to": [{"email": "raghu.iitr@gmail.com", "name": "Raghvendra Singh", 
 "type": "to"}], "merge": true, 
 "merge_vars": [{"rcpt":"raghu.iitr@gmail.com",
 "vars":[{ "content:": "random template", "name": "TEMPNAME" }, { "content:": "raghu", "name": "USERNAME" }]}] }}'
 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json'
```

I get the following response

```
[{"email":"raghu.iitr@gmail.com","status":"sent","_id":"9015df4d0b1b457588670863c7303822","reject_reason":null}]
```

But the email i get doesn't merge the variable and here is the email i get

```
Hello *|USERNAME|* this is a *|TEMPNAME|* template
```

I am not sure what am i doing wrong here. Any kind of help is really really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made a typo in the JSON. `"content:": "random template"` should be `"content": "random template"` and `"content:": "raghu"` should be `"content": "raghu"`. There should be no colon after content inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

For your syntax in the message variable you should have add a field 'merge_language' => 'mailchimp'